# Can no more choose something than something?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> For them, one can no more choose one’s sense of obligation to a group,
>   or the lack of it, than one can choose one’s personality.
>
> The Moral Foundation of Politics by Ian Shapiro

I don't understand the connection between **no more** and **than**. 
What does **no more choosing something than something** means?
Or am I getting this sentence wrong? Can please someone explain this sentence to me?

Answer (score 3):

A. Can one choose one's sense of obligation to a group?

B. Can one choose one's personality?

The author thinks one can **not** choose one's personality, and claims that choosing one's obligation to a group is not possible either.

If B is impossible, and
A is no more possible than B
then A is also impossible.

A simpler example might clarify things:

I would **no more** *buy designer shoes* **than** *throw my money away*.

There is a variant of this structure, using "sooner":
I would **no sooner** argue with him **than** I would bark at my dog.